# How to install Covergloobus?

Tags: 11.04, music, covergloobus

I like Ubuntu 11.04 very much.
But I miss Covergloobus. Is there a way to install it in Natty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is and I am using it. Just grab the deb files and install using `gdebi` or `dpkg -i`.

[amd_64](https://launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/covergloobus/+files/covergloobus_1.7-6_amd64.deb)

[i386](https://launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/covergloobus/+files/covergloobus_1.7-6_i386.deb)

You can grab from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/covergloobus) as well or [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/covergloobus-1-7-release-candidate-ppa/).

Comment: but the ppa is maverick and lucid only ? it does not work on natty. But I will dry the .debs and Ill report if it worked.

Comment: Donot add the ppa, just download the deb file from packages section or above link and install it.