# Alternative to Panflute Applet?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, indicator, applet, audacious

I use Audacious as my music player, and was using [Panflute Applet](http://launchpad.net/panflute) to control the playback right from the superior menu bar.

As I recently upgraded to Natty Narwhal, and it doesn't support applets anymore, I can no longer use it.

Can you guys suggest something similar to this applet (maybe there's an indicator that controls media playback, but I couldn't find it) that works with Natty?

Here's a screenshot of the applet:

[image: panflute applet]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like panflute is going to be [abandoned](https://launchpad.net/panflute/+announcement/7933). As rhythmbox and banshee are both integrated with sound menu, I think you could either choose one of the following. Or you could use [Covergloobus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35201/how-to-install-covergloobus) which says it supports [audacious](https://launchpad.net/covergloobus) but you wont have as much control as sound menu. As for alternative to panflute, I donot know of any such applications.

Or you may just enable systray icon of audacious. I am using audacious that way.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, type "gnome-panel" into a terminal, to get your old panel back, then fiddle until you get the functionality of both unity and gnome's panels. More info here: http://www.xp4g.net/linux/get-your-favourite-gnome-panel-applets-and-alt-f2-run-dialog-back-in-ubuntu-11-04-unity/