# How can I install CoverGloobus in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, covergloobus

I tried installing from source code but it isn't installed. I tried [sagarchalise's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/35219/1114327) on [How to install Covergloobus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35201/) but that also didn't work. How can I install CoverGloobus in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last version of this software was released in 2011 year.

You have to download the deb-package of it and install it manually by commands below:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/cg
cd ~/Downloads/cg
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/gloobus-dev/covergloobus/ubuntu/pool/main/c/covergloobus/covergloobus_1.7.3_amd64.deb

sudo apt install python-is-python2 python-dbus 
sudo apt install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb ./covergloobus_1.7.3_amd64.deb
```

and enjoy.